# Seeking option to symbolize layer using chart in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, fields-attributes, chart

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

My layer includes ~20 beach sites, along with the counts of different debris types for each site (e.g. glass debris, metal debris, etc). I want to symbolize these types in either a bar graph or a pie chart for each site, but the "chart" option is not showing up under symbology. The options are features, categories, quantities, and multiple attribute. The debris fields are all doubles.

Any suggestions on how to get an option for charts?

Comment: Point, line, or polygon layer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very comprehensive documentation about this in [ArcGIS website](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/about-symbolizing-layers-to-represent-quantity.htm#GUID-C2655811-1326-4F95-BE1C-4A068430F3DD):

[image: usingchart]

Pie Chart: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-features-to-show-quantities-drawing-pie-ch.htm

Bar / Column Chart: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-bar-and-column-charts.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response - I understand how to use the chart feature, but ArcGIS is not giving me the option to do so when symbolizing the layer. I'm trying to understand why the chart option is unavailable, not how to use the chart tool. Any suggestions?